# locally commit data issue in XCode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I was working fine and my all the functionalities was working good.Suddenly , my Xcode is stop committing data. I searched a lot. I restart Xcode and my machine too but no changes.I removed all unimportant projects from organizer.I have created new repository but no change again. I am fade up with with issue. When i am trying to commit my code it's not showing me an error but there is no changes in files."M" is still in from of my files.Please help me to solve this issue.Why this is happening.

I don't know but automatically too many files were created in my project.Like it was created in too many folders like Create Folder virus.I have deleted those 3356 files from my project and it's showing those file name with bellow comments

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm ..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)

After this getting these some lines

Untracked files:
  (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)

```
SquaresGame.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/
SquaresGame.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/atidan.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/
SquaresGame/Assets/Images/SquaresGame.ipa
```

Comment: Well to solve the issue we are going to have to go through some steps using the command line.  Firstly, go to the project directory and type `git status` and post the output (in your question, not as a comment).

Comment: @trojanfoe: Hi , i have added those line into my question please check it.

Comment: I got the issue but still not having proper solution.I unchecked those files which are deleted and commit my code..It works..but everytime i can't follow this process